# Rest API to query for Products and prices

Tags: soql, rest

I have been asked to design some new forms that create Orders in Salesforce. To achieve this I call the webservices often using Query.  For these new forms that are related to Ordering I had hoped to Query the Product2/PriceBook2/PriceBookEntry objects as this is where the data is stored.

I am currently testing via hurl.it and the URL to call (with the correct authorisation) is simplified to this query:

https://XXXX.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Product2

Which returns the error code:

> INVALID_TYPE

The query is simply:

```
SELECT Id FROM Product2
```

This works in the developer console.The user does have activate orders and edit activate order permission.

Can anyone confirm if it is simple NOT Possible to query these objects in this fashion?  What is an alternative (this is simple...enough for me).?

If it is not possible to query, I am able to hard code the products onto the form I am developing (they don't change often and there aren't many) and then create the Order/Line Items directly via the Web Service (including Activating it) - I haven't got this far but I hope it is all possible.

Comment: by any chance is product to a custom object, maybe you need to use the API name -> Product2__c in the query

Comment: Hi, I am afraid it is the standard objects.  The query: SELECT Id FROM Product2 works and returns what I expect if queried either via WorkBench OR the developer console.  Thanks.

Comment: what JS library are you using in the app to call SF ?

Comment: I should emphasise that at the minute I am actually testing via hurl.it.  The IDE isn't playing a part yet (I will edit the question to remove that - it is unnecessary (question now edited).

Comment: Its working - I missed something obvious! See answer - Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: good to hear you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was permissions:

The API user I was using simply record **Read** access to **Products** and **Price Books**.

I would usually delete this question to avoid embarrassment but too late for that.

Comment: might as well accept your own answer =P

Comment: Yeah I know - 2 day restriction on that though so I couldn't  until now.